# How can I add a key attribute column before storing it into Azure SQL DB?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am using Data Factory to shift data from a Data Lake Storage Gen2, transform the data and finally I want to store the data in an Azure SQL DB.

How can I add a column with an key attribute (bigint) based on the rowNumber()? I tried to use the functionality "Derived Column", but I can't choose the function rowNumber() as it is only valid for window transformations.

Thanks

Comment: If you're just looking for a sequential unique row number, I would use the Surrogate Key transformation.

Comment: Hi @Matzka, If the answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Surrogate key transformation in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-surrogate-key).

Create the key based the row number of the data:

[image]

[image]